# Cannot solve system of linear equation sums?

Tags: equation-solving, version-9

I cannot get mathematica to solve:

[image]

The problematic code:

```
With[{n = 7}, 
 Solve[((2*
       Sum[((Subscript[y, 
             k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
              c*Subscript[x, k] + d)))*(-Subscript[x, k]^3), {k, 1, 
         n}]) == 0) && ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-Subscript[x, k]^2), {k, 1, 
         n}]) == 0) && ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-Subscript[x, k]), {k, 1, 
         n}]) == 0) && ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-1), {k, 1, n}]) == 0), {a, b, 
   c, d}]
 ]
```

I tried for a variable `n`, but that gave me 'could not solve with methods available to Solve', so then via a recommendation here I used n=6, but this still doesn't seem to work :/

If I put $x_{k}$ and $y_{k}$ instead as $x[[k]]$ and $y[[k]]$ and give a list however, then it is able to solve in under a second, as shown in this example:

```
x = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 6];
y = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 6];
With[{n = 6}, 
 Solve[And @@ 
   Table[Sum[(y[[k]] - (a x[[k]]^3 + b x[[k]]^2 + c x[[k]] + 
           d)) (-x[[k]]^j), {k, 1, n}] == 0, {j, 0, 3}], {a, b, c, d}]]

(*
==> {{a -> -0.0970828, b -> 0.771442, c -> 0.895965, 
  d -> -3.73369}}
*)
```

Here is a version of this code that doesn't work:

```
Clear[x, y]

With[{n = 6}, 
 Solve[And @@ 
   Table[Sum[(Subscript[y, 
          k] - (a Subscript[x, k]^3 + b Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
           c Subscript[x, k] + d)) (-Subscript[x, k]^j), {k, 1, n}] ==
      0, {j, 0, 3}], {a, b, c, d}]]
```

Comment: Is the variable `x` a list of values? If yes then you should use `x[[k]]` instead of using a subscript.

Comment: I added my version of the code to the question to make it easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 5):

I tried your example in version 8 and had no problems solving it. To save typing, I shortened it as follows:

```
With[{n = 6},
 Solve[
  And @@ Table[
    Sum[(Subscript[y, 
         k] - (a Subscript[x, k]^3 + b Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
           c Subscript[x, k] + d)) (-Subscript[x, k]^j), {k, 1, n}] ==
      0, {j, 0, 3}],
  {a, b, c, d}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: output]

Then I confirmed that it works identically for this input where I eliminated all the subscripted variables:

```
With[{n = 6}, 
 Solve[And @@ 
   Table[Sum[(y[k] - (a x[k]^3 + b x[k]^2 + c x[k] + d)) (-x[k]^
          j), {k, 1, n}] == 0, {j, 0, 3}], {a, b, c, d}]]
```

So the use of `Subscript` is perfectly fine here, and makes no difference in version 8.

However, in version 9 *neither of the above produce a solution* before I had to abort the calculation. So this is probably a bug, and it will take a little more thought to find a work-around.

One can write the equations explicitly as a linear system by calculating the matrix containing the sums of powers of $x_k$ (which can be summed independently of the unknown variables). I tried to do this with the original lengthy code in the question, and then used [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html):

```
With[{n = 7},
  equations = {
    ((2*Sum[((Subscript[y, 
             k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
              c*Subscript[x, k] + d)))*(-Subscript[x, k]^3), {k, 1, 
         n}])), ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-Subscript[x, k]^2), {k, 1, 
         n}])), ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-Subscript[x, k]), {k, 1, 
         n}])), ((2*
       Sum[(Subscript[y, 
            k] - (a*Subscript[x, k]^3 + b*Subscript[x, k]^2 + 
             c*Subscript[x, k] + d))*(-1), {k, 1, n}]))
    }
  ];

Clear[a, b, c, d];
m = D[equations, {{a, b, c, d}}];
vec = -equations /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {0, 0, 0, 0}];
LinearSolve[m, vec]
```

Here, I converted the system of equations to a matrix of linear coefficients (`m`) and a vector `vec`. Again, **this hangs** in version 9 but produces a solution in version 8. So the work-around for now seems to be: *use version 8* (as I do by default, too).

Comment: any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: I just tried my `LinearSolve` idea and again can't get it to work in version 9 while it works in 8. See my edit.